# Working with a serial device using System.IO.Ports, knowing VID and PID in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core

I know the VID and PID of my serial device, how can I find the name of this device in Linux, for further use of this name in SerialPort.

In Windows, I can use [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DhW4.png) to find the device by VID and PID.
What are some alternatives for Linux?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.